# How to Prevent An Inline Embed From Pushing Text Down (CSS)

Tags: css, inline

Hi i am having a problem with my inline embeds. They are pushing my text down or canceling out the horizontal align and i don't know how to correct it.

Here is my (HTML) code:

```
<div id="WindMax">
<embed src="WeatherIcons/UpArrow.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="E25px" />
77
<span class="Set">mph</span>
</div>
```

And the (CSS) code:

```
embed {
margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0;
display:inline;
}
embed.E25px {
width:25px; height:25px;
}
embed.E30px {
width:30px; height:30px;
}
span.Set {
font:bold 15px 'Arial Narrow',Arial,Sans-Serif;
text-align:center;
display:inline;
}
#WindMax {
background:;
position:absolute;
width:100px; height:25px;
margin:45px 0 0 570px;
font:bold 25px/25px 'Arial Narrow',Arial,Sans-Serif;
text-align:left;
z-index:-996;
}
```

Cheers in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for your embedded image: `vertical-align: middle;`